# Optimization problem in matrix space

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

We want to prove a function defined over space of symmetric matrices. In particular, I’m studying the problem
\begin{align*}
\min_{A\in\mathbb{S}^n} f(A)-\langle A,B\rangle
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
f(A)=\frac{1}{n}\|A\|^2-\frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{tr}(A)^2
\end{align*}
with $B\in\mathbb{S}^n$ and inner product is $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(AB)$. We want prove that if $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$ then problem has solution. I already proved that $f$ is convex and differentiable, so that to conclude I need to prove that $f$ is coercive if $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$. How could I prove this?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to any future readers who might benefit from that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Frobenius norm. Let $a=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}(A),\,b=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}(B),\,\Lambda=A-aI$ and $Z=B-bI$. That is, let $\Lambda$ and $Z$ be the traceless parts of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(A)&=\frac{1}{n}\|A\|_F^2-\frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{tr}(A)^2-\langle A,B\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\|\Lambda+aI\|_F^2-a^2-\langle \Lambda+aI,Z+bI\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\|\Lambda\|_F^2+\frac{1}{n}\|aI\|_F^2-a^2-\langle \Lambda,Z\rangle-\langle aI,bI\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\|\Lambda\|_F^2-\langle \Lambda,Z\rangle-nab\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\|\Lambda-\frac{n}{2}Z\|_F^2-\frac{n}{4}\|Z\|_F^2-nab.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
If $B$ is not traceless ($b\ne0$), then $g$ has not any local or global minimum because $g(A)\to-\infty$ when $A=aI$ and $ab\to+\infty$. If $B$ is traceless ($b=0$), then global minima of $g$ occur at $\Lambda=\frac{n}{2}Z=\frac{n}{2}B$, i.e., they are given by $A=\frac{n}{2}B+aI$ where $a$ is arbitrary.